# How can I delete my own question?

Tags: discussion, support

**It may seem funny but can I actually delete my own question on SF?**

For example, what if I have a question that doesn't need to be answered any more? As time passes the situation has changed, other solutions (that are related to that question) for that particular problem are found and I am not able to provide any more assistance nor effort for answering that question thus making it almost impossible to be answered.

Well by now you all get my point.. :)

In that case I may want to delete the question so that **it nobody bothers** any more. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: In situations where you solve or work around it yourself, you could answer it yourself and accept your own answer, of course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Users with enough rep can delete their own questions, but lower rep users can't, because it's often abused by deleting questions that others have put input into.

So, if you really want your question deleted, flag it for moderator attention, stating you want it deleted, and more importantly, *why*. If it's got no answers and few views, we'll delete it. But if we deem that other people have put in a lot of effort, or if its a very popular and helpful question to others, we'll leave it be.